# ASP.NET validators error message in client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

The error message that gets added to the validation summary when the form is invalid I need to get access to in client-side JavaScript.  How do you access the actual message?  My page doesn't have a ValidationSummary present, and `Page_Validators[0].errormessage` is *.  Where is the message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bad setup on my part; was trying to set it up too quickly.  It did work when you set the error message correctly :-)

Answer here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1560042/3853155.aspx